# How to get past the electricity in the corridor at the beginning of Chapter 4?

Tags: half-life

I'm playing the original Half Life and I've gotten up to the part in the corridor (Chapter 4: Office Complex) where there is electricity zapping the ground from the ceiling.

Even if I'm far away it still kills me, so how do I get past it? Can I stop it somehow?

Answer (score 6):

Position yourself towards the corridor with the hanging cables that are electrified. Behind you is a locked room with some scientists which you want to enter.

Turn towards the electricity. On the bottom of the right wall is a ventilation duct. Enter the duct and go to the right. You will enter the locked room. Watch out for the hidden barnacles. On the opposite side of the room to the right is a door, inside is a switch that will disable the power for that part of the map.

[image]